# Not able to render line chart using d3.js for various date range

Tags: d3.js

I am preparing line chart using d3.js. Wherein I have to create chart for different types of date range on x axis. For example,

For 1 month data
**01-01-2018** to **31-01-2018** . This is working fine.
But when I truncate data from database and only prints for months. Like,
**FEB-2018** & **MAR-2018** ... **It is showing repeated values on x axis ... Instead it should show only 1 value for whole month** ..

For better understanding, I have prepared the same problem on github.

Please check the link below .
[Problem Reproduced with code](http://blockbuilder.org/hitarth19/0295f89b15da5ec03bc1a20644182ce8)

Comment: There is not a single repeated value here. You deliberately chose to format the ticks with `"%b-%Y"`. If you want a different axis, change that format.

Comment: @Gerardo : There are repeated values. I mean on x axis "JAN-2016" is repeated 5 times. "FEB-2016" repeated 4 times. same as "MAR-2016"

Comment: Again, there is **no** repeated value, each tick represents a **different** date, but you are formatting the ticks to show only month and year. That's very simple. Who wrote this code, you?

Comment: Ok . got that .. Instead I checked the scalePoint() function of d3.js